# How to pass Cucumber tagName from a yml file in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, tags, cucumber

I need to pass the Cucumber tagname from an external file (run.yml) as below

```
execution:
  tag: '@Regression'
```

How to pass to runner class. My current runner class is as below and execution doing from meven or directly from junit

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        tags = "@Regression" ,
        features = "features",
        glue = "io/automation/gluecode",
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"}
)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

I tired to implement with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774099/pass-cucumber-options-dynamically-in-cucumber-junit), but it is not working in latest cucumber

```
  RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions = new RuntimeOptions(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(argv)));
        MultiLoader resourceLoader = new MultiLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        ResourceLoaderClassFinder classFinder = new ResourceLoaderClassFinder(resourceLoader, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        Runtime runtime = new Runtime(resourceLoader, classFinder, this.getClass().getClassLoader(), runtimeOptions);
```

unable to locate `MultiLoader` class

Comment: How are you launching Cucumber? Specifically, how does your `TestRunner` class get executed? Maven? Gradle? Something else?

Comment: I am running my RunnerClass from maven or by Junit

Comment: Did you try passing the property `mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@Regresion`?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I am able to execute with cli cucumber commands, but I need to pass the tags from a yml file, where I am adding all execution details and which need to execute via maven and Junit run.

Comment: Cucumber only looks at system, environment and property files. I reckon you need to see how you configure that from your yaml file. Shouldn't be too difficult if the yaml file is for a ci system.